# How to Fill Page with Empty Cells using material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to fill the rest of a table on a page with empty cells if the data does not fill the whole page. Here is my code so far. I am using react.js and material ui.

```
import { Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, TableRow } from "@material-ui/core";

function DashTable() {
    const data =[
      { id: 1, name: "John Doe", Id: 12345, startDate: "2023-07-31", endDate: "2023-08-31", groupType: "Group A" },
      { id: 2, name: "Jane Smith", Id: 67890, startDate: "2023-08-01", endDate: "2023-09-30", groupType: "Group B" },
      { id: 3, name: "Michael Johnson", Id: 54321, startDate: "2023-08-15", endDate: "2023-10-15", groupType: "Group C" }
    ]
    return (
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Checkbox</TableCell>
            <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
            <TableCell>First Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Second Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Start Date</TableCell>
            <TableCell>End Date</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Group Type</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            <TableRow key={index}>
              <TableCell><input type="checkbox" name="radio-box" /></TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.id}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.name}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.Id}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.startDate}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.endDate}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.groupType}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>

    )
}

export default DashTable;
```

I have tried calculating the remaining height of the viewport but that doesn't work well